# Optimize performance of text rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a `<p>` tag inside of a `<div>` that has the following properties:

```
div {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

When the page loads, I want to keep adding words to the `<p>` tag until I detect an overflow, as in stop when the the first word to not be shown is added.

I do this using the following code:

```js
var textToRender = "People assume I'm a boiler ready to explode, but I actually have very low blood pressure, which is shocking to people.";
var words = textToRender.split(" ");

var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var p = document.getElementById("myp");

var i = 0;
while (p.clientHeight <= div.clientHeight && i<words.length) {
  p.textContent += words[i++] + ' ';
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 55px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <p id="myp"></p>
</div>
```

Now say I do this on a much bigger scale with a larger div. Take this one step further and say I need to do this for 50 divs of different sizes with different text. Obviously even though to our eyes this seems to be happening instantaneously, in reality every word has to get drawn one by one.

I want to figure out how to optimize this sort of operation assuming I don't know the line-height, container div height, or number of words. My question is: if I place an opaque `<div>` ontop of the container to cover this one-by-one word drawing, then remove it when the function has detected an overflow, will this boost performance because the actual words wouldn't be getting drawn on each iteration of the while loop?

If not, are there any similar tactics I could use to optimize this sort of operation?

Answer (score 0):

Try binary search. That is what you want.

```js
var textToRender = "People assume I'm a boiler ready to explode, but I actually have very low blood pressure, which is shocking to people.";
var words = textToRender.split(" ");

var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var p = document.getElementById("myp");

var l = 0, r = words.length, m;
while (l < r) {
  m = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
  p.textContent = words.slice(0, m).join(' ');
  if (p.clientHeight <= div.clientHeight /* maybe you need add an additional line height here */) l = m + 1; else r = m - 1;
}
p.textContent = words.slice(0, l + 1).join(' ');
```

```css
div {
  height: 55px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <p id="myp"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good use of binary search!